# change address search function to a name ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Im new to ruby on rails, i have a code currently it searches for address I need to change it. instead of searching for address i need to search for a field called item_name.

home.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "What you looking for?", class: "form-control", id: "autolocation" %>
    </div>
 </div>
```

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @items = Item.where(active: true).limit(3)
  end

  def search

    # STEP 1
    if params[:search].present? && params[:search].strip != ""
      session[:loc_search] = params[:search]
    end

    # STEP 2
    if session[:loc_search] && session[:loc_search] != ""
      @items_address = Item.where(active: true).near(session[:loc_search], 100, order: 'distance')
    else
      @items_address = Item.where(active: true).all
    end

    # STEP 3
    @search = @items_address.ransack(params[:q])
    @items = @search.result
    @arrItems = @items.to_a

  end

  end

end
```

Comment: Not related to your question: It seems like (1) you may have an errant `end`, and (2) the `STEP 2` conditional is unnecessary given your `STEP 1` conditional.

Comment: Instead of going through nested hash one by one, try using `dig` from ruby http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig, you can rewrite your `if session[:loc_search] && session[:loc_search] != ""` line using that in a much cleaner way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to work by doing this

```
  if session[:loc_search] && session[:loc_search] != ""
     @items_names = Item.where('item_name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
  else
    @items_names = Item.where(active: true).all
  end

  @search = @items_names.ransack(params[:q])
  @items = @search.result

  @arrItems = @items.to_a
```

Comment: `session[:loc_search]` can return 3 things: nil, non-blank string, blank string.  If it's nil, then the else executes.  If it's blank, then the else executes.  If it's a non-blank string, then the if clause executes.  Now, let's see what happens if your if statement were just: `if session[:loc_search] != ""`.  If it's nil, the else executes.  If it's blank then the else executes.  If it's non-blank, then the if clause executes.  In other words, exactly the same result as your compound conditional.

Comment: @7stud so do I should just use either one not both

Comment: Let's see what happens if you use just: `if session[:loc_search]`.  If it's nil, then the else executes.  If it's blank then the if clause executes--that's because the only things that are false in ruby are false and nil.  if it's non-blank, then the if clause executes.  Not what you want.